# How to convert Word document to pdf without losing header formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

When converting word document to pdf a number in the header changes from 01 to 001.

How can we fix that?

Comment: WHat have you tried so far? What are you using to convert it to PDF?

Comment: Is the number dynamically generated (page number, section number, etc) or just standard text?